# Using adaptive LASSO penalty for a logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, lasso, glmnet

So I have this code for running adaptive LASSO in R

```
library(glmnet)

train = data.matrix(train)
test = data.matrix(train)
train_X = subset(train, select = -c(Category))
train_y = subset(train, select = c(Category))
test_X = subset(test, select = -c(Category))
test_y = subset(test, select = c(Category))

n = nrow(train)

lambdas = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 10.0)

ridge <- cv.glmnet(x = train_X, y = train_y, alpha = 0, family="multinomial", lambda=lambdas, type.measure = 'class', nfold= n, grouped=FALSE)
best_ridge_coef <- as.numeric(coef(ridge, s = ridge$lambda.min))
alasso <- cv.glmnet(x = train_X, y = train_y, family="multinomial", alpha = 1, penalty.factor = 1 / abs(best_ridge_coef), lambda=lambdas)

ada_model_coef = coef(alasso, s = alasso$lambda.min)
y_pred = predict(alasso, test_X, s = alasso$lambda.min, type="link")
```

The target is a Bernoulli and what's coming back in y_pred, might be correct? But I don't know how to interpret it.

```
                 0           1
  [1,]  1.42888292 -1.42888292
  [2,]  1.41375071 -1.41375071
  [3,] -0.75950680  0.75950680
  [4,]  1.43786886 -1.43786886
  [5,]  1.37787921 -1.37787921
  [6,]  0.27880898 -0.27880898
  [7,]  1.47372331 -1.47372331
  [8,]  1.41583441 -1.41583441
```

This is what's in y_pred. Seems like maybe some sort of weightage for class 0 or 1? I don't really know.

I think setting family='multinomial' is fine the only options are family = c("gaussian", "binomial", "poisson", "multinomial", "cox", "mgaussian") according to the docs. I had to set family="binomial" for the initial ridge regression, because the returned coefficients can't be applied to adaptive lasso when it's set to 'multinomial' cause it's a list.

Comment: You may want ``predict(alasso, test_X, s = alasso$lambda.min, type="response")`` for the probabilities.